# How to update custom content type fields value in bulk?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities, database

Is their any way to provide the bulk edit in the custom content type fields values by csv or in bulk.?

Answer (score 1):

Without a lot of detail about your problem I suggest you research these modules:

- [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)
- [Views Bulk Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_edit)
- [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)
- [documentation for the Feeds module for Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/feeds)

VBO works through Views: you create a list of the nodes you want to edit. VBO provides a field through which you can select nodes (checkbox) and then you can perform operations on them.

Feeds can update existing nodes from a CSV file (create new nodes too). They're a bit trickier to configure, mapping must be tested thoroughly and you need to make sure the entries are unique, but once you have them set up correctly you can use them over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Migrate Source CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv)

> The basic [Migrate framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) went into core for Drupal 8 - but not all
>   of it. The core migrate module will implement the underlying
>   framework, while the migrate_drupal module will support simple
>   upgrades from Drupal 6 and Drupal 7. The rest of the migration
>   functionality from Drupal 7 will be left to contrib to implement. <strike>This
>   project is the contrib functionality for CSV files.</strike> Over in #2931739:
>   [Bring migrate_source_csv to core](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2931739), it was decided to port this module
>   for use in core. Eventually, this module will sunset

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-a-csv-source)